# JS string together text input from multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a js fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/80/

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<div>
<button class="buttons">d</button>
<button class="buttons">o</button>
<button class="buttons">g</button>
<button class="buttons">s</button>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
    });

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $('input.active').val(cntrl);

    });

      $( "#next" ).click( function() {
       alert("When user clicks next button I would like the input from all 4 textboxes strung together into a word and alerted---like 'dogs' in this example");  
      });
});
```

How can I 'string' together the characters from each textbox to alert the word 'dogs' for instance in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `#next` click you can put in a foeach button to capture all the input fields.

```
$( "#next" ).click( function() {
    var completeString = "";

    $('input').each(function(){
        completeString += $(this).val();
    });

    alert(completeString);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/87/)

HTML:

```
<input id="d" type="text">
<input id="o" type="text">
<input id="g" type="text">
<input id="s" type="text">
<div>
    <button class="buttons" value="d">d</button>
    <button class="buttons" value="o">o</button>
    <button class="buttons" value="g">g</button>
    <button class="buttons" value="s">s</button>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).val();
        $($('input').get($(this).index())).val(cntrl);
    });

    $("#next").click(function () {
        var toAlert = $('#d').val() + $('#o').val() + $('#g').val() + $('#s').val();
        alert(toAlert);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each of jquery like the below.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9zn9gLw/1/

```
$( "#next" ).click( function() {
       var str = "";
      $( ".buttons" ).each(function(  ) {

         str += $(this).html();
        });

      alert(str);

  });
```

*Please mark as answer if it answers your question*

Answer (score 0):

looping through input text will solve this

```
$( "#next" ).click( function() {
      var text = '';
      $.each($('input[type="text"]'),function(v,k){
        text += $(k).val();
        });
      alert(text);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/85/